# How to stop copying the white space, on a blank line, in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In visual studio code, if you press ctrl + c on a blank line, with nothing highlighted, it copies the blank line.

I thought there may was an option to disable this, but haven't been able to find it.

Comment: There is an option in (regular) Visual Studio for "Apply Cut or Copy commands to blank lines when there is no selection."  I don't know if VSCode has a similar option, but that's some text you might look for.

Comment: I wanted the opposite of the OP. The setting `editor.emptySelectionClipboard: true` works, but not when the vim extension is enabled :-(

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You should be able to do this by configuring the option `editor.emptySelectionClipboard` to `false`.

Comment: "editor.emptySelectionClipboard": false    Works GREAT!  :)

Comment: For me, this disables copying/cutting a line with ctrl-c/x when I have nothing selected. I only want to disable cutting lines that only contain whitespace...

Comment: If you don't like how the command works, you probably need to write your own extension or request an enhancement on the [issues page](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues). (I didn't write the code that implements the behavior you don't like, so it's a bit pointless to complain about it here.)

Comment: Is there a similar option in Visual Studio 2022 too? I can't find it

Comment: @Fabio it's in Options->TextEditor->General "Cut or Copy the current line without selection"  I don't know why anyone would ever want that to be turned on.  I've accidentally duplicated lines so many times, causing build failures, just because there was no selection.

Comment: @N.McA. Have you ever found a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

There is an extension for it:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.do-not-copy-empty

Comment: Cool.  Might as well just change the settings with it being built in and all.

Comment: cool, but this extension works only with CTRL + C, not with CTRL + X

Comment: better than changing settings cause you don't lose the "copy line" functionality