# Copy to clipboard on empty selection in the Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard-interaction

I would like to disable the default copy on empty selection in the Jupyter notebook. A corresponding problem in the Sublime text editor can be solved easily as explained in an answer to the [Sublime: how to disable empty copy](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-disable-empty-copy/32952) question (similarly for VSCode as in [How to stop copying the white space, on a blank line, in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587843/how-to-stop-copying-the-white-space-on-a-blank-line-in-visual-studio-code)).

Jupyter scenario: whilst the text selection is empty, press the copy keyboard shortcut (ctrl+c / command+c).

Current behavior: copies the current line to clipboard, overwriting its content.

Expected behavior: do nothing and keep the clipboard content intact.

Please avoid flame wars: I realize this is a feature for some people and I don't ask for changing the defaults. However, I find it useful not to lose the copied selection by mistake while hitting ctrl+c / command+c instead of ctrl+v / command+v and having to go through ctrl+z stack popping. Peace!